How do I test a MOSFET/IGBT for its maximum current and maximum voltage mentioned in the datasheet practically?
I am using an IGBT from Infineon (IGW25N120H3FKSA1). The datasheet mentions that the absolute maximum ratings for the IGBT are Vce(max) = 1200 V and Ic(max) = 25-50 A (depending on temperature). How do I test it practically and verify if the IGBT actually handles 1200 V and 25-50 A? For e.g. a pulse tester circuit helps test the switching of MOSFETs and IGBTs; what would a circuit that tests voltage and current limits be called?

Be careful and make sure you read the entire datasheet, including notes. Not all the ratings are meant to be reached simultaneously or at plausible thermal conditions.

Why do you want to test this?  While any manufacturer can screw up, in general you buy from a manufacturer that you can trust, then you trust them.  Unless it's done very carefully, testing parts to their absolute ratings will carry a risk of damaging them, thereby doing the opposite of what you're probably trying to achieve.

I would call that device an adjustable power supply with current limit capabilities. For pulse testing, you can get by with a capacitor bank and a much smaller power supply.

The way this is done in industry (that is, to take data needed to write the datasheet) is by using either a curve tracer like a Tektronix 370A, a semiconductor parameter analyzer like the Agilent/Keysight B1505, or custom software controlling a bunch of SMUs.
Production tests (where you verify that every individual part, or a sample of parts, meets specifications) are done using dedicated test equipment manufactured by companies like Tesec or FocusedTest; this is highly specialized equipment that you're not likely to find outside of a testing lab. These tests require specialized equipment because they have to be fast--even a test time of 1 second would take a week and a half to test a million parts.

You can measure VCES by applying the specified current.  Typically through a large-value resistor from a high voltage supply, to avoid potential capacitive discharge events that will likely destroy the device (IGBTs rarely handle much if any avalanche breakdown).
Current rating might be inferred from VCE(sat) curve, give or take tempco.  This parameter is contingent on TJ, which is not as easy to measure as it is for BJT or MOSFET devices.  VGE(th) might be a method.  A double-pulse method could be used, where VGE(on) is applied (at large VCE and IC), then reduced, such that IC becomes set to a given value (e.g. the 0.85mA of Fig.12; notice you need to measure and calibrate this curve for your particular device under test (DUT) to do this measurement).
...Haha wow, full DC SOA, don't see that often on IGBTs either.  Well, that makes thermal pulse testing easier, I suppose.
You can also crack open an extra device and check that the die area is as expected.  You'll have to message the manufacturer and check what it is; Infineon has a responsive (if not necessarily accurate or helpful?) counterfeit reporting channel that may be of assistance here.
Preferably, use heat to soften the plastic and pry the die out without damaging it (or hot acid to burn away the package), then use a microscope to view markings (if any) on the chip itself.
